# Codeceptjs only works when installed globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-testing, codeceptjs

When I open the instructions to install [CodeceptJS](http://codecept.io/quickstart/) it offers the option to install the node_module both locally and globally. However only global install works. When I install codeceptjs locally in my express application then try to initialize the codecept install I get "bash: codeceptjs: command not found". Any ideas?

nodejs - v6.2.2, express - v4.13.4, using a mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install it locally, most likely it's not in your $PATH. You need to specify the full path to it. Assuming you're in the root of your project, type: `./node_modules/.bin/codeceptjs`

Or you can re-export the PATH variable to include this path (unadvised).

Comment: You can also create an NPM script. If you add something like `"scripts": { "at": "codecept run" }` in your package.json, you can run your tests without having to worry about the local path since NPM handles that for you: `npm run at`

Comment: That too! Actually may prove to be a better solution is it's going to use it multiple times. For a one-time call, you can just specify the path directly.

Comment: thanks...you were correct about needing the directory in front of the node_module command name. We shortened them by adding scripts to the package.json. Now we can use 'npm run [script_name]'

Comment: Running from the command line, `npx codeceptjs run --steps tests/00-login.test.js`   with no space at the end gives 'codeceptjs command not found'  add the space and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

`"./node_modules/.bin/codeceptjs" run --steps` should work fine